# Changing state but then clearing input React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

I'm writing my first React app and really struggling to do something quite basic.

I have an Input component that has an array in state, which, when it has two numbers, it sends them and a unique ID as an object up to a parent Component which stores the object in an array.

This is all fine and I can do it. The problem is clearing the inputs afterwards.

So far as I understand it, I need the value of the inputs to be stored in the Component state (in the array) when I do an on Change. Those values are then used for submitting the form.

However, if the inputs are getting their value from state, they need to have a value on render, which I don't want. I only want them to have a value *after* I've entered something into the input. I've tried using setState to replace the inputTable with an empty array after submission, but that's still not changing the values.

Here's the code - to reiterate, I want to find a way to just clear the inputs after I've submitted the array. At the moment it keeps saying that I'm changing an uncontrolled component into a controlled one, which I understand, but I don't understand how else I'm meant

Please trust that I've tried to solve this by myself, checking out MDN docs about forms and inputs, but I'm really not getting anywhere. I'd really appreciate the help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputTable: [],
      uniqueId: 1
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.sendTables = this.sendTables.bind(this);
  }

  async handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    await this.setState({
      inputTable: [
        ...this.state.inputTable, e.target.value
      ]
    })
    console.log(this.state.inputTable)
    // how do I handle this onChange correctly?
  }

  async sendTables(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.submitTable(this.state.inputTable, this.state.uniqueId);
    let newArray = [];
    await this.setState({
      inputTable: newArray,
      uniqueId: this.state.uniqueId + 1
    })
    console.log(this.state.inputTable)
    // how can I clear the inputs?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Input">
        <form action="" onSubmit={this.sendTables}>
          <input required type="number" name="value0" placeholder="a number..." onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.inputTable[0]} />
          <span>X</span>
          <input required type="number" name="value1" placeholder="multiplied by..." onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.inputTable[1]}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Add times table" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Input;
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from './Input/Input';

class InputTimesTables extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tables: [],
      noInputs: 1
    }
    this.pushToTables = this.pushToTables.bind(this);
  }

  addInput() {
    // this will be used to add an additional input
    // it will increment no. inputs
  }

  async pushToTables(arr, id) {
    let newTimesTable = {
      timesTable: arr,
      uniqueId: id
    }

    await this.setState({
      tables: [...this.state.tables, newTimesTable]
    })
    // console.log(`The ITT state looks like:`, this.state.tables);
    //this will take the two numbers in the array from the Input 
    // and push them to the tables array
    // it won't run unless there are two numbers in that array
    console.log('The main state array now looks like this: ', this.state.tables)
  }

  // clearTables(id){
  //   console.log(`splicing array no ${id}`);
  //   let newArray = this.state.tables;
  //   newArray.splice(id, 1);
  //   this.setState({
  //     tables: newArray
  //   })
  //   console.log(this.state.tables);
  //   // console.log(`The ITT state looks like:`, this.state.tables);
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>                
        <Input submitTable={this.pushToTables}/>
        <h3>Currently being tested on:</h3>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InputTimesTables;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share your parent component please?

Comment: yes will do now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it - the issue is that a number input is not actually a number - it's a string. So I can just set the arrays to ["", ""] and then reset them, and there's no problem. I hope this helps someone else if they run into it.

Thanks if you had a look!